# Speech Recognition: prosody. What is the difference between combined and intergrated models?

Tags: prosody, speech-recognition

I am readin a paper about dialogue modelling and the identification of dialogue acts using prosody. The paper describes 2, maybe three types of model for utilizing the speech signal: a separate, sequential model and EITHER a combined and intergrated model OR a combined model, and an intergrated model. It's not clear.

Is there a difference between a combined model and an intergrated model or should I count those together? If there is a difference, then what is it?

Comment: You'd better provide a paper title or, better, a link to a paper.